# Embedding word document in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

I have a requirement to display word document in ASP.NET form. Also, the original word format has to be retained. In a nutshell i have to embed a word document in a web form programatically. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the clients that are browsing the site are going to have Word installed and use Internet Explorer, you could [embed it with an ActiveX object](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/03736117-fc0f-4232-9c14-2aef79db83da). If these requirements are not met you might need to convert it to some more standard format that a browser is capable of displaying such as a `jpeg` image. You may also look at this [option](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/WordinWeb01202007101216AM/WordinWeb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are html embed tag options to embed pdfs into the html page. So probably you need to convert the doc into pdf before.

Check here. http://blog.flashcolony.com/?p=244

This works for me. But may need newer versions of Adobe Reader.